# Event Handling for leap years

Tags: javascript

for javascript the questions are
The user should enter a year into the Enter Year text field. The leap year text field should display “yes” if the number entered is a leap year, and “no” if it is not. I have to use a key press event handler

this is the javascript that I use, this javascript is not working

```
function myFunction()
("Enter A Year");
if  x = (year % 100 === 0) ? (year % 400 === 0) : (year % 4 === 0);    
if(x){
 ("This Is A Leap Year");
  document.getElementById("x")
  }else{
   function myFunction ()
 ("This Is Not A Leap Year");
 document.getElementById("z")
 }
 }
```

and this is the html I use

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Leap Year</title>
<script src="worksheet7.js" type="text/javascript" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Leap Years</h1>
<input id="x" onkeyup="myFunction()"> Enter Year
<input id="z" onkeyup="myFunction()"> is it a leap year?

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to look at some tutorials about basic javascript: defining variables, functions, calling functions, etc.

Comment: @vazed your function has too many syntactic errors.

Answer (score 0):

Use below function to test for Leap Year :

```
function leapYear(year) {
  if (year % 400 === 0) {
    alert("It is a leap year");
  } else if (year % 100 === 0) {
    alert("It is not a leap year");
  } else if (year % 4 === 0) {
    alert("It is a leap year");
  } else {
    alert("It is not a leap year");
  }
}
```

JsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/nikdtu/dd8xuqb6/

Answer (score 0):

You have many syntax errors. So you need to review some tutorials about basic javascript. However this code should be what you're after.

```js
document.getElementById("x").onkeyup = function() {
  var year = parseInt(this.value);
  var isLeapYear =  ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)) || (year % 400 == 0);
  document.getElementById("z").value = isLeapYear ?  'yes' : 'no';
}
```

```html
<h1>Leap Years</h1>
<input id="x"> Enter Year
<br />
<input id="z" readonly> is it a leap year?
```